# Scalatest PlusPlay Selenium not able to resize a window

Tags: javascript, scala, selenium, scalatest

Been digging at this for a while, and I can't seem to find a way to resize a window using scalatest plus.

The only method I've found searching online or the documentation at http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.5/index.html#org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser

is 
    executeScript("window.resizeTo(700,700);")

but that has been unresponsive to me (no errors, no nothing).  Is there a method that covers this that I am missing?  A brief sample of my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import org.openqa.selenium._
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.TODO
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import controllers.Application
import models.{Item, ItemPriorityBucket}
import play.api.test._
import org.scalatest.time._

class WebSpec extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite with AllBrowsersPerTest {

  implicit override val patienceConfig =
    PatienceConfig(timeout = scaled(Span(5, Seconds)), interval = scaled(Span(20, Millis)))

  override lazy val browsers = Vector(
//    FirefoxInfo(firefoxProfile),
    ChromeInfo
//    SafariInfo
  )

  implicit override lazy val app: FakeApplication =
    FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = TestUtil.inMemoryDatabase("default", Map()))

  val base: String = "http://localhost:" + port

  def sharedTests(browser: BrowserInfo) = {

    "Home page" should {
      "render an item" + browser.name in {
        executeScript("window.resizeTo(700,700);")
        Item.deleteAll()
        delete all cookies

        val itemId = TestUtil.createRandomItem(Some(ItemPriorityBucket.Low), Some(Application.ENGLISH))
        val item = Item.find(itemId).get

        go to (base + "/")
        eventually { assert(cssSelector(Selectors.all_items).webElement.isDisplayed) }
      }
    }
  }
```

One of my tests will see different elements based on the window size, so this is something I need to control, but I can't really find any help out there for doing this in Scala.

Thanks for the help,

EDIT:  I should also mention that other scripts run using execute script are functioning as expected, just not the resize window script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the following line of code:

```
webDriver.manage.window.setSize(new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(1000, 600))
```

it's not very intuitive, since we have to explicitly access the implicit webdriver, but it works.